# Name FOO is not bound in this Context

Tags: java, tomcat

I have this java code

My properties file has this: `jndi.lookup.base = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb`

```
 public static Connection getDBConnection(String jndiName) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context webContext = (Context)initContext.lookup(MyProperties.getInstance().getProperty("jndi.lookup.base", "java:comp/env"));
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) webContext.lookup(jndiName);
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

I get this error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc:mysql:].

I saw a bit on the internet and it seems I need to add something to the Tomcat's context.xml.  How?

My context.xml

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
```